# Non alpha character arrowlabels on a diagram

Tags: r, diagram, label

The `R` package `diagram` has been giving me some very nice flow charts.  Here is a simple example:

```
install.packages("diagram")
require(diagram)
A = matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2, data = 0)
A[2,1] = "hello"
par(xpd = NA)
plotmat(A, name = c("A", "B"))
```

I would like to change the arrowlabel (currently set as "hello") to be "(+)".  So,

```
A[2,1] = "(+)"
plotmat(A, name = c("A", "B"))
```

But this fails:

```
Error in parse(text = x, ...) : <text>:1:3: unexpected ')'
1: (+)
     ^
```

Is there a set of escape characters, or some other trick, that will force `parse` to interpret my symbols as simple text?  Of course, a workaround is to use `text` to place text on the plot, but I'm hoping to take advantage of `plotmat's` built-in label positioning functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
A[2,1] = "`(+)`"
plotmat(A, name = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]